# For cubic $P(x)$ with a root in $[0,1]$, find the smallest $C$ such that $\int_0^1 |P(x)|dx\leq C\max_{x\in[0,1]}|P(x)|$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, optimization, integral-inequality

> Find the smallest constant $C$ such that for every polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $3$ with a root in $[0,1]$,
>
> $$\int_0^1 |P(x)|dx\leq C\max_{x\in[0,1]}|P(x)|.$$

Here's my rough work. Write $P(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$. Then $$\int_0^1 P(x)dx=\dfrac{a_3x^4}{4}+\dfrac{a_2x^3}{3}+\dfrac{a_1x^2}{2}+a_0x.$$ I think I'm supposed to assume something about $P(x)$ to make the problem easier. That might be that $\max_{x\in[0,1]} P(x)=1$. I'm not sure if I can assume that $P(x)$ is always positive over the interval. Also, for the case that $P(x)$ has $3$ roots in the interval $[0,1]$, I can split the interval into the intervals $[0,I_1], [I_1,I_2],[I_2,I_3]$, where $I_1,I_2,I_3$ are the roots of $P(x)$. I suppose I can also assume $P(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: From $P(x) = 1 + (x-1)(2x-1)^2$ it follows that $C\geq \tfrac56$.

Comment: @WimC  It appears that it is the solution.